# How to Parse JSON data from a URL and append to a UiLabel with Swift 5

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to get data from Json url for this specific line "ConfirmedCount" from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlankerL/DXY-COVID-19-Data/master/json/DXYOverall.json to a UiLabel that I created but keeps getting error. I have been trying to do this for week now.

Here is my code:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var labeltest: UILabel!

    //the json file url
    let URL_HEROES = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlankerL/DXY-COVID-19-Data/master/json/DXYOverall.json";

    //the label we create
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTest: UILabel!

    //A string array to save all the names
    var nameArray = [String]() 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //calling the function that will fetch the json
        getJsonFromUrl()
    }

    //this function is fetching the json from URL
    func getJsonFromUrl(){
        //creating a NSURL
        let url = NSURL(string: URL_HEROES)

        //fetching the data from the url
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {

                //printing the json in console
                print(jsonObj.value(forKey: "results")!)

                //getting the avengers tag array from json and converting it to NSArray

                if let heroeArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "results") as? NSArray {
                    //looping through all the elements
                    for results in heroeArray{

                        //converting the element to a dictionary
                        if let heroeDict = results as? NSDictionary {

                            var  confirmedCount: Int

                            //getting the name from the dictionary
                            if let confirmedCount = heroeDict.value(forKey: "confirmedCount") {

                                //adding the name to the array
                                self.nameArray.append((String (format: "1234", confirmedCount as! Int)))
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    //calling another function after fetching the json
                    //it will show the names to label
                    self.showNames()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }

    func showNames(){
        //looping through all the elements of the array
        for confirmedCount in nameArray{
            labelTest.text = (confirmedCount)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
(
        {
        abroadRemark = "";
        confirmedCount = 80422;
        confirmedIncr = 120;
        curedCount = 49923;
        curedIncr = 2663;
        currentConfirmedCount = 27515;
        currentConfirmedIncr = "-2581";
        deadCount = 2984;
        deadIncr = 38;
        generalRemark = "\U7591\U4f3c\U75c5\U4f8b\U6570\U6765\U81ea\U56fd\U5bb6\U536b\U5065\U59d4\U6570\U636e\Uff0c\U76ee\U524d\U4e3a\U5168\U56fd\U6570\U636e\Uff0c\U672a\U5206\U7701\U5e02\U81ea\U6cbb\U533a\U7b49";
        note1 = "\U75c5\U6bd2\Uff1aSARS-CoV-2\Uff0c\U5176\U5bfc\U81f4\U75be\U75c5\U547d\U540d COVID-19";
        note2 = "\U4f20\U67d3\U6e90\Uff1a\U65b0\U51a0\U80ba\U708e\U7684\U60a3\U8005\U3002\U65e0\U75c7\U72b6\U611f\U67d3\U8005\U4e5f\U53ef\U80fd\U6210\U4e3a\U4f20\U67d3\U6e90\U3002";
        note3 = "\U4f20\U64ad\U9014\U5f84\Uff1a\U7ecf\U547c\U5438\U9053\U98de\U6cab\U3001\U63a5\U89e6\U4f20\U64ad\U662f\U4e3b\U8981\U7684\U4f20\U64ad\U9014\U5f84\U3002\U6c14\U6eb6\U80f6\U4f20\U64ad\U548c\U6d88\U5316\U9053\U7b49\U4f20\U64ad\U9014\U5f84\U5c1a\U5f85\U660e\U786e\U3002";
        remark1 = "\U6613\U611f\U4eba\U7fa4\Uff1a\U4eba\U7fa4\U666e\U904d\U6613\U611f\U3002\U8001\U5e74\U4eba\U53ca\U6709\U57fa\U7840\U75be\U75c5\U8005\U611f\U67d3\U540e\U75c5\U60c5\U8f83\U91cd\Uff0c\U513f\U7ae5\U53ca\U5a74\U5e7c\U513f\U4e5f\U6709\U53d1\U75c5";
        remark2 = "\U6f5c\U4f0f\U671f\Uff1a\U4e00\U822c\U4e3a 3\Uff5e7 \U5929\Uff0c\U6700\U957f\U4e0d\U8d85\U8fc7 14 \U5929\Uff0c\U6f5c\U4f0f\U671f\U5185\U53ef\U80fd\U5b58\U5728\U4f20\U67d3\U6027\Uff0c\U5176\U4e2d\U65e0\U75c7\U72b6\U75c5\U4f8b\U4f20\U67d3\U6027\U975e\U5e38\U7f55\U89c1";
        remark3 = "\U5bbf\U4e3b\Uff1a\U91ce\U751f\U52a8\U7269\Uff0c\U53ef\U80fd\U4e3a\U4e2d\U534e\U83ca\U5934\U8760";
        remark4 = "";
        remark5 = "";
        seriousCount = 6416;
        seriousIncr = "-390";
        suspectedCount = 520;
        suspectedIncr = 143;
        updateTime = 1583295001876;
    }
)
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/AbdalQaydi/Desktop/jnews/jnews/ViewController.swift, line 84
2020-03-04 00:26:49.829895-0500 jnews[12702:1192396] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/AbdalQaydi/Desktop/jnews/jnews/ViewController.swift, line 84
(lldb)
```

It looks like it can parse the data but I don't know how to add the json data for line "confirmedCount" to label.

Please any help is really appreciated. I have been trying to figure out how to do this and just can't find a way.

Comment: Although it's pretty bad *unswifty* code (don't use `NSURL`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `valueForKey` and `.allowFragments`) the parsing doesn't cause the error. Most likely the outlet is not connected. Consider that the label is declared twice with different spelling.

Comment: @Abdal Qayadi, I have noticed `labeltest` is declared twice. remove one of the label and make sure you have given connection from the storyboard. the same code works for me, when I remove duplicate `labeltest`.

Comment: Please highlight the code line you received an error

Comment: @abdal Qaydi: Make sure you have done with connection 'labeltest' to UI.

Comment: I was wondering, why there was no compile time error, when you create duplicate label. @All, Any idea?

Comment: @Sravan please have a closer look at the variable names: `labeltest` and `labelTest` are different.

Comment: Yeah thanks @vadian. I missed that. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use **`Codable`** to parse the *JSON* `data`.

**Models:**

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let results: [Result]
    let success: Bool
}

struct Result: Decodable {
    let currentConfirmedCount, confirmedCount, suspectedCount, curedCount: Int
    let deadCount, seriousCount, currentConfirmedIncr, confirmedIncr: Int
    let suspectedIncr, curedIncr, deadIncr, seriousIncr: Int
    let generalRemark, abroadRemark, remark1, remark2: String
    let remark3, remark4, remark5, note1: String
    let note2, note3: String
    let updateTime: Int
}
```

**Parse** the `data` like,

```
if let url = URL(string: URL_HEROES) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
                let confirmedCountArr = response.results.map { String($0.confirmedCount) }
                nameArray.append(contentsOf: confirmedCountArr)
                //rest of the code...
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: It's a great suggestion but it doesn't fix the error 

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and I was able to fix the issue. After a week I was able to fix it with simply adding "\(confirmedCount)" and removed an empty label that was not connected. Thanks again! I'll try that as well for my next project.